# Adding nonstandard files to a checkinstall package

Tags: linux, compile, checkinstall

I am experimenting with checkinstall to manage custom builds of software. I would like to add custom files to a package, e.g. /etc/init.d/nginx when installing nginx.

The `--include` parameter is a simplistic way of achieving this, but it seems a bit clunky to create, say, `etc/init.d/nginx` in the nginx source directory in order for that file to be included in the package.

Is this this accepted way of injecting custom files into checkinstall packages?

Answer (score 1):

> --include: Force  the  inclusion in the package of the files/dirs listed in the argument (a file).

You need to create a file containing files paths you want to add.

In your case, `--include=files_to_add` where `files_to_add` contains the line `etc/init.d/nginx`